# Java.sql.Connection событие выполнения sql запроса

Tags: java

Есть что-то подобное? Я хочу в этом обработчике выводить в лог выполняемые запросы, или это можно сделать как-то по-другому?

Comment: @kidar2 Вам событие или лог? Обычно под событием в программировании имеется ввиду некий хэндлер/хук к которому можно прицепить некое действие/вызов и проч. Ну а лог это лог

Comment: Я хочу в обработчике события писать в свой лог

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача решается с применением шаблона [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

```
// класс который будет писать все в лог
public class LogConnection implements Connection
{
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger ( getClass ().getName () ) ;
    private final Connection delegate ;

    // пример переопределенного метода который пишет что-то в лог
    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement ( String sql ) throws SQLException
    {
        log.info ( "Creating new prepared statement = " + sql ) ;
        return delegate.prepareStatement ( sql ) ;
    }

    // пример переопределенного метода который нас не интересует
    public void close () throws SQLException
    {
        // вы обязательно должны в своем класе вызывать метод делегата
        delegate.close();
    }

    ... другие методы которые нас не интересуют ....
}
```

Пример использования:

```
/* базовый класс для DAO обьектов, пронаследовався от которого вы получите необходимый вам функционал, т.к. connection автоматически wrapped, хотя лучше конечно это делать там где вы конструируете свой connection */
public abstract class BaseDao
{
    private Connection connection ;

    public BaseDao ( Connection connection )
    {
        setConnection ( new LogConnection ( connection ) ) ;
    }

    protected Connection getConnection ()
    {
        return connection ;
    }

    protected void setConnection ( Connection connection )
    {
        this.connection = connection ;
    }
}
```

p.s. по аналогии можно сделать что-нить подобное для любого интересующего вас класса

Comment: А как LogConnection получить если я получаю Connection через DriverManager?

Comment: вы не переопределили **CreateStatement()** и написали, что другие методы(в частности **close()**) вас не интересуют. Не надо так!

Comment: Я бы так конструктор сделал:
  
     public BaseDao(String host, String dbName, String name, String   passwd)throws SQLException
     {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          String url = 'jdbc:mysql://'.host.'/'.dbName;
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, passwd);
          

     }

А потом сделал бы рефакторинг и получил бы Синглтон. Потому что создавать новый экземпляр **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** не нужно

Comment: > вы не переопределили CreateStatement() и написали, что другие методы(в частности close()) вас не интересуют. Не надо так!
Я разделил все методы на 2 логические группы "те которые нас интересуют" (в которые надо добавить вывод в лог) и "те которые нас НЕ интересуют" (делегирование вызова). И привел по 1му примеру для каждой из них, все логично. Пусть автор сам решает для каких ему надо добавлять а для каких нет.

Comment: > Я бы так конструктор сделал:

добавлять такой код в конструктор данного класа - ошибка проэктирования. обьекта DAO должен использовать `connection`, но не должен управлять его состоянием. В вашем примере данное BaseDao может быть использовано только в качестве базового дао для субд `MySql` в то время как класс в изначальном виде не имел таких ограничений. касательно рефакторинга - не совсем применимо в случае если уплавлением конекшнами будет заниматся `application server`

Comment: обьекта DAO должен использовать connection, но не должен управлять его состоянием

Не спорю, но нашему юзеру не обязательно предоставлять самому инициализировать драйвер и выбирать реляционная БД или нет. Он подразумевает, что работает с **MySQL**, так может стоит инкапсулировать этот код?

Comment: у меня есть несколько вопросов к вам: зачем вы пытаетесь обьяснить мне очевидные вещи касательно инициализации `connection` ? какое отношение `MySql` имеет к паттерну `delegation` ? каким образом то что вы навязываете автору топика поможет решить его проблему?